# Problema ao tentar criptografar e descriptografar usando RSA

Tags: java, criptografia, rsa

Olá, estou fazendo um programa que criptografa um arquivo gerado pelo usuário e depois descriptografa o arquivo criptografado mostrando a mensagem original. É que nem o código de implementação RSA do *Bouncing Castle* mas salvando os arquivos.

Só que não estou conseguindo passar os dados criptografados do arquivo gerado pelo usuário. Ele se mostra vazio.

```
package br.com.rsa;

import java.security.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.crypto.*;

public class Geracao {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //Gerando um arquivo que será encriptado e descriptografado.
        Scanner entrada1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite qualquer coisa: ");
        String entrada = entrada1.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Arquivo criado.");

        FileOutputStream saida = new FileOutputStream("arquivo.txt");
        PrintStream imprimir = new PrintStream(saida);
        System.setOut(imprimir);
        System.out.println(entrada);
        saida.close();

        //Gerando as chaves publica e privada.
        try {       
        KeyPairGenerator chave = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        chave.initialize(1024);

        KeyPair chaves = chave.generateKeyPair();

        PrivateKey privada = chaves.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publica = chaves.getPublic();

        Base64.Encoder cripto = Base64.getEncoder();

        System.out.println("Chave privada: " + cripto.encodeToString(privada.getEncoded()));
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Chave publica: " + cripto.encodeToString(publica.getEncoded()));
        System.out.println("");


            //Salvando as chaves publica e privada.
            try (FileOutputStream s_prv = new FileOutputStream("privada" + ".key")){

                s_prv.write(chaves.getPrivate().getEncoded());

            }

            try (FileOutputStream s_pub = new FileOutputStream("publica" + ".key")){

                s_pub.write(chaves.getPublic().getEncoded());
            }

            Criptografar(chaves, null);
            //Descriptografar(chaves, null);
        }

        //Qualquer erro dentro da geração das chaves
        catch (Exception e){

            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    //TODO - Comentario
     static private void processFile(Cipher cifra, InputStream entrada_arq_c, OutputStream saida_arq_c){
           try {
            byte[] ibuf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = entrada_arq_c.read(ibuf)) != -1) {
                byte[] obuf = cifra.update(ibuf, 0, len);
                if ( obuf != null ) saida_arq_c.write(obuf);
            }
            byte[] obuf = cifra.doFinal();
            if ( obuf != null ) saida_arq_c.write(obuf);
           }
          catch(Exception e) {

              System.out.println("Problema no manuseio do arquivo.");
          }
    }

    //Metodo para criptografar.
     static private void Criptografar(KeyPair chaves, Cipher ci){
        try {
            PublicKey publica = chaves.getPublic();
            Cipher cifra = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cifra.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publica);

            FileInputStream entrada_arq_c = new FileInputStream("arquivo.txt");
            FileOutputStream saida_arq_c = new FileOutputStream("criptografado.txt");
            processFile(ci, entrada_arq_c, saida_arq_c);

        }
        catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Erro ao criptografar.");
        }
    }

    //Metodo para descriptografar.
     static private void Descriptografar(KeyPair chaves, Cipher ci){

        try {
            PrivateKey privada = chaves.getPrivate();
            Cipher cifra = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cifra.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privada);

            FileInputStream entrada_arq_c = new FileInputStream("criptografado.txt");
            FileOutputStream saida_arq_c = new FileOutputStream("descriptografado.txt");
            processFile(ci, entrada_arq_c, saida_arq_c);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Erro ao descriptografar.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Que parte do algoritmo está a funcionar corretamente e que parte não está ? Apresenta algum erro ? Se sim qual ?

Comment: O unico problema é que quando eu chamo o metodo criptografar, ele ate cria o arquivo só que ele está vazio.

Comment: Esta fechando os streams (`close()`) depois que escreveu? Na dúvida faz um `flush()` também.

Comment: @Piovezan Consegui uma resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui uma resposta para o problema. Fiz a mesma pergunta na parte em inglês do site e precisei somente substituir isto

```
processFile(cifra, entrada_arq_c, saida_arq_c);
```

Foi necessário substituir o ***ci*** por ***cifra***. Fora acrescentado também uma linha a mais no Exception do método *processfile*.

E por final, foi adicionado uma linha a mais onde salvo o arquivo, acrescentando

```
PrintStream defaultOutStream = System.out;
System.setOut(defaultOutStream);
```

Para que assim que terminar de salvar o arquivo do usuário, ele retomar depois da chamada do *saida.close();* para imprimir na tela.

Para quem quiser ver uma versão mais detalhada da solução, irei postar o link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254880/problem-with-encrypting-and-decrypting-using-rsa-on-java?answertab=active#tab-top